# SQL Search Between a Range with a Range

Tags: php, sql, range

I have a table on my site that are home builders. They build homes between a specific range, say $100,000 to $700,000. I'm trying to make that searchable to a user who is looking for a builder who builds within there own submitted range, say $200,000 to $250,000. Any suggestions to do this? I know I can use BETWEEN to search if an integer is between a range, but how would I search for a range within a range?

Ex:

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_posts WHERE meta_price_range BETWEEN 200000 AND 300000
```

Comment: Please, post a query trial and, if possible, table structure

Comment: Why bother with the outer ranges?  If all you care about is returning the values between 200 and 250K just use that in a between clause.

Comment: I agree, but this is for builders who build between certain price ranges.

Comment: @Robert Moskal -- If one range is not a subset of the other, things become interesting.  I assume that is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suits You?

```
select * from 
( select  50000 as low, 250000 as high from dual ) client,
( select 100000 as low, 700000 as high from dual ) builder
where 
   client.high between builder.low and builder.high
or client.low  between builder.low and builder.high ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_id 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE 
    (builder_price_range BETWEEN 200000 AND 700000)
    AND
    (buyer_price_range BETWEEN 400000 AND 500000)
```

Obviously filling in the parameters will be interesting; would need more information from you on how to take care of that.